# FB login window on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

How to enable Facebook login window on modal?
Something like that on the image.

[image]

but mobile equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the Facebook JavaScript SDK, Note: this runs in frontend not on Backend.

```
    function getScript(u, c) {
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], s = document.createElement('script')
      s.async = true
        s.src = u
      s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!s.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(s.readyState)) {
          s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = null; if (h && s.parentNode) { h.removeChild(s) } s = undefined
          if (c) { c() }
        }
      }
      h.insertBefore(s, h.firstChild)
    }
```

Now Fetch the FB JS SDK and Initialise FB API like this:

```
getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=yourappidhere', () => {
  if(typeof window.fbAsyncInit === 'undefined') {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'you app id',
      version: 'your app version',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      frictionlessRequests: true,
      useCachedDialogs: true,
      oauth: true
    })
  }
})
```

Now, when add an event listener to your login button:

```
document.querySelector('your-btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  FB.login((response) => {
    // your callback
  })
})
```